# How to reset arduino Mega 2560 code automatically?

Tags: arduino

I am working on the temperature project using arduino to collect temperature. But sometimes arduino hang there so I have to unplug cord and plug it back in to restart the arduino. I do not when it is going to hang up again. So I decide to do some research on the internet but no luck for that. Here is [the article](http://sysmagazine.com/posts/189744/) I read about resetting arduino code with watchdog timer library.(unfortunately, it only work for arduino uno) If someone has any idea how to reset arduino mega 2560 code. Please help !!

Comment: You should consider to ask it on [An arduino stackexchange website](http://arduino.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Try reading asm datasheet and beware of answers that merely point the program counter.  That's not the same as a full reset.

Answer (score 1):

You can reset the Arduino using the following syntax:
First declare a function

```
    void(* resetFunc) (void) = 0;//declare reset function at address 0
```

Then call the function wherever you want to reset the controller.

```
    resetFunc();
```